# calculate the total number of odd elements in a list

Tags: python

```
arr=[13,15,4,6,8,71,45,54,56,77,67,88,49,33838,3784376,77735] 
for num in arr:
  if num % 2 != 0:
    a = sum(num)
    print(a)
```

Output:

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due because "num" is just an element inside your list and sum functions needs to receive an iterable, if you just want to count the odd elements inside arr you can use:

### If you want to count the odd elements

```
oddsCounter = len([x for x in arr if x % 2 != 0])
print(oddsCounter)
```

### If you want to get the total sum

```
oddsSum = sum([x for x in arr if x % 2 != 0])
print(oddsSum)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `sum` on an `int` (num). You can do the following:

```
arr = [13, 15, 4, 6, 8, 71, 45, 54, 56, 77, 67, 88, 49, 33838, 3784376, 77735] 
count = 0
for num in arr:
  if num % 2 != 0:
    count += 1
    print(count)
```

or more simply:

```
print(sum(num % 2 == 1 for num in arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `list comprehension`,

```
In [1]: sum([i for i in arr if i %2 != 0])
Out[1]: 78072
```

And, `sum(int)` is not possible because `sum` only takes iterable (list, tuple, etc.) as the argument.

Answer (score 0):

`sum` only accepts iterables, not single items.

try this:

```
a = a + num
```

take a look at this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_sum.asp) to learn more about `sum`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `a = sum(num)`. `sum()` takes an array but you have given it a int.

The code should be like this:

```
total = 0
arr=[13,15,4,6,8,71,45,54,56,77,67,88,49,33838,3784376,77735] 
for num in arr:
  if num % 2 != 0:
    total = total + 1
print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looping over the list, thus `num` is the current element in the iteration. You want to use `sum` on an iterable such as below:

```
> arr = [13,15,4,6,8,71,45,54,56,77,67,88,49,33838,3784376,77735]
> sum(num % 2 == 0 for num in arr)
8
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get them with a list comprehension:

```
arr=[13,15,4,6,8,71,45,54,56,77,67,88,49,33838,3784376,77735]
elems = sum([ 1 if num %2 != 0 else 0 for num in arr])
print(f"Number of odd elements: {elems}")
```

Checkout as you are trying to sum the value of the "num" itself. Not sure if you were trying to append it to a list onto a.

Answer (score 0):

im no sure what you mean by total number of odd elements as in all the times theres a odd number or the sum of all the odd numbers but here

```
arr=[13,15,4,6,8,71,45,54,56,77,67,88,49,33838,3784376,77735] 
a = 0
for num in arr:
  if num % 2 != 0:
    a += num
print(a)
```

sum is used on lists so if you realy wanted to use the sum it looks like this

```
arr=[13,15,4,6,8,71,45,54,56,77,67,88,49,33838,3784376,77735] 
a = []
for num in arr:
  if num % 2 != 0:
    a.append(num)
print(sum(a))
```

Answer (score -1):

try using *[modulo](https://realpython.com/python-modulo-operator/)* and *[list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp)*

```
arr=[13,15,4,6,8,71,45,54,56,77,67,88,49,33838,3784376,77735]

def odd_elements(arr):
    return len([x for x in arr if x % 2 != 0])

print(odd_elements(arr))
```

or, using [sum()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/sum)

```
arr=[13,15,4,6,8,71,45,54,56,77,67,88,49,33838,3784376,77735]


def odd_elements(arr):
    return sum(1 for i in arr if i % 2)

print(odd_elements(arr))
```